# Cannot Efficiently Loop SequenceAction

Tags: java, libgdx

Why doesn't this work and how do I fix it/create a different, working loop for this `SequenceAction`?

```
public void setLoopingFade(float time)
{
    fadeLoop = Actions.sequence(Actions.fadeOut(time), Actions.fadeIn(time), Actions.run(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                fadeLoop.restart();
            }
        }));

    this.addAction(fadeLoop);
}
```

`fadeLoop` is a `SequenceAction`.
I'm adding the `SequenceAction` to an `Actor`.

**Clarification**
Ok, so what I want to do is fade my actor in and out repeatedly. I figured the best way to do this was to create a `SequenceAction` that I would loop. The looping is what the `Runnable` is for. However, this method does not work. The fading out and back in happens once and then nothing. Even though the action is still owned by the `Actor`. I have also tried calling `fadeLoop.reset()`, however, that does not work either and actually makes the issue worse, because, when calling `restart()` I can still restart the `SequenceAction` manually from a different class, but when calling `reset()` the action loses all functionality.
I have tried adding a boolean functionality that would alert the external class to restart the action, but because the action ends after changing the boolean, it is removed from the actor and despite re-adding the action, it still does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using [Actions.forever(Action repeatedAction)](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/Actions.html#forever-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Action-) ?

**Example :**

```
fadeLoop = Actions.forever(Actions.sequence(Actions.fadeOut(time), Actions.fadeIn(time)));
this.addAction(fadeloop)
```